# gedit syntax highlighting issue

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gedit

In gedit 3.28.1 in Ubuntu 18.04, I have syntax highlighting random problem :

[image]

In the above image you can see that `\linewidth` (on line 24) highlights the way regular control sequences are set in green. However, `\linewidth` as part of the second argument for `tabularx` is not highlighted. Similarly for `\Nb` and `\Centering`.

How can we update gedit to properly highlight the LaTeX syntax?

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry I thought that it was obvious seeing highlighted or not highlighted command in parallel. Thank you to the one who guessed. One temporally solution is to use latex.lang from the previous version. I tried a diff, but there is a lot of differences and I can't guess which one is good one.